# How can i enable fingerprint logon for RDP sessions from Windows 10 like in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, fingerprint, biometrics

[image: Screenshot is of Windows 8 mstsc.exe client letting me logon with just the swipe of the finger.]

Screenshot is of Windows 8 mstsc.exe client letting me logon with just the swipe of the finger.

Windows 10 does not provide this capability, how does one enable it for Windows 10. Yes, i have a PIN and Windows Hello with fingerprints is setup, but not this feature.

Comment: The anniversary edition of Windows 10 does not work either.  Anybody tested all the dev editions.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 made some changes to the way the biometric authentication, including fingerprint, works in order to improve security. Because of this, RDP with fingerprint login is not currently supported in Windows 10. But looks like face authentication works in current version.

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/f30211ff-f6ba-49fb-a72c-3bb9bac7c65f/fingerprint-for-creds-no-longer-works-for-rdp-sessions?forum=win10itprosecurity&prof=required)

Comment: facial recognition only works with a couple of specific IR cameras.  We specifically purchased Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga because they had a fingerprint reader.

Comment: i was hoping by now that you would have edited your answer to footnote the verbatim answer on [Microsofts website from last August](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/f30211ff-f6ba-49fb-a72c-3bb9bac7c65f/fingerprint-for-creds-no-longer-works-for-rdp-sessions?forum=win10itprosecurity&prof=required).  Copying and pasting an answer verbatim is fine as long as attribution is given.

Comment: Thank you for adding a Source.